# R readlines() font issue

Tags: xml, r, readlines

I am using the following code to get text from a website

```
readLines("http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/duits/synoniemen/abartig")[181]
```

and it reads the first synonym on the url mentioned as "bÃ¶se" but it should be "böse".
Help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
readLines("http://www.mijnwoordenboek.nl/duits/synoniemen/abartig", encoding="UTF-8")[181]
```

In the html of the webpage, there is a line that states the charset is "UTF-8":

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

you have to manually specify this parameter in [readLines](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/readLines.html)

Comment: Can you also suggest a alternate way to get 181 line without reading full page?

Comment: @Bansal I don't think I can do that with readLines. You can also try RCurl

Comment: If i further pass output form the above code to htmlTreeParse() it again changes the characters to weird ones. and specifying encoding="UTF-8" doesn't help there.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your R settings.

```
options()$encoding
```

I am running OSX and your example was fine for me.
If your encoding is not UTF-8, then change it by

If you are using R studio,

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding

Or function

```
 enc2utf8(yourstring)
```

Comment: Can you also suggest a alternate way to get 181 line without reading full page?